# No data exists for the row/colum when there is data

Tags: c#, sql, .net, ms-access, oledbdatareader

i have this code

```cs
public static PersonalData[] GetAllPersonalInfo(OleDbCommand cmd)
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT count(Id) FROM PersonalInfo";
            int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Id From PersonalInfo";
            OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            PersonalData[] output = new PersonalData[count];
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                output[i] = GetOnePersonPersonalInfo(reader.GetValue(0), cmd);
                reader.Read();
            }
            reader.Close();
            return output;
        }
```

which is supposed to go through every entry in a database and get the data and put it in a custom class. but when it reaches the `reader.GetValue(0)` part it throws an `System.InvalidOperationException: 'No data exists for the row/column.'` error. i used the debugger to see the values and this is what i found.
[image: debugger]

there is clearly some data in the reader but it dosn't output it. what am i missing?

Comment: _reader.Read_ should be before the attempt to extract data. When a DataReader is built its initial position is not on the first record. You need a Read to advance to the first record and then go on

Comment: You need to call `Read` to read the first row too

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the **reader.Read** first. Also instead of applying for a loop, you can simply use a while loop for better code performance.
Also, remember to check whether the reader has data or not by using **HasRows**.

```
if (!reader.HasRows)
    {
        // No data to read
        reader.Close();
        return new PersonalData[0];
    }

    List<PersonalData> output = new List<PersonalData>();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        output.Add(GetOnePersonPersonalInfo(reader.GetInt32(0), cmd));
    }
```